# How to call all methods in object in loop?

Tags: python

I have an object that has different methods like `SGD`, `Adam`, `Adamax` and I can call it like this:

```
optim.SGD(parameters, lr, momentum=0.9)
optim.Adam(parameters, lr, momentum=0.9)
optim.Adamax(parameters, lr, momentum=0.9)
```

How can I call it all in the cycle. I have the following algo:

```
models = [..., ..., ...]
lrs =    [..., ..., ...]
criterions = [..., ..., ...]

for model in models:
    for criterion in criterions:
        for lr in lrs:
            optimizer = optim.SGD(model.params(), lr=lr, momentum=0.9)
            train(model=model,
                  criterion=criterion,
                  optimizer=optimizer,
                  lr=lr)
```

How can I call `train()` with all `optimizer`'s algorithms that I mention(`optim.SGD`, `optim.Adam`, `optim.Adamax`)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr)  to get the `train` attribute of each optimizer, then call it:

```
...
getattr(optimizer , 'train')(model=model,
                              criterion=criterion,
                              optimizer=optimizer,
                              lr=lr)
```

There's also [`operator.methodcalller`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) which does exactly the same thing with a slight change of syntax:

```
from operator import methodcaller

...
methodcaller('train', model=model,
                  criterion=criterion,
                  optimizer=optimizer,
                  lr=lr)(optimizer)
```

Answer (score -1):

Directly enumerate the optimize function

```
models = [..., ..., ...]
lrs =    [..., ..., ...]
criterions = [..., ..., ...]

optim_funcs = [optim.SGD, optim.Adam, optim.Adamax]

for model in models:
    for criterion in criterions:
        for lr in lrs:
            for func in optim_funcs:
                optimizer = func(model.params(), lr=lr, momentum=0.9)
                train(model=model,
                      criterion=criterion,
                      optimizer=optimizer,
                      lr=lr)
```